# FirstName (VARCHAR) is not showing up I get Error: Column does not exist: Firstname

Tags: sql, postgresql

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmRVv.png)

```
CREATE TABLE employee  
( 
    PersonID integer,  
    FirstName varchar(30),  
    LastName varchar(50),  
    Age integer,  
    HiredDate date  
);  

INSERT INTO employee (PersonID, Firstname, LastName, age, HiredDate)  
VALUES  
    (01, 'Alan', 'Palmer', 32 , '2019-12-15'),  
    (02, 'Susan', 'Shepard', 28 , '2015-07-21'),  
    (03, 'Justin', 'Ward', 43 , '2017-08-24'),  
    (04, 'Alan', 'Smith', 30 , '2017-06-22') ,  
    (05, 'James', 'Betternot', 26 , '2017-06-22') ,  
    (06, 'Ralph ', 'White', 44 , '2017-06-23') ,  
    (07, 'Lenord', 'Nemoy', 72 , '2007-12-14') ,  
    (08, 'Janice', 'Rand', 61 , '2016-07-06') ,  
    (09, 'Harry', 'Mudd', 65 , '2020-07-06') ,  
    (10, 'Hikaru','Sulu',58,'2015-03-21'),  
    (11, 'James', 'Kirk', 59, '2014-01-02'),  
    (12, 'Leonard ','McCoy', 65, '2015-08-21'),  
    (13, 'Pavel','Chekov', 44, '2014-10-15'),  
    (14, 'Christopher', 'Pike',Null, '2014-11-24'),  
    (15, 'Darth','Vader',Null,'2015-03-22'),  
    (16, 'Boba', 'Fett',Null,'2015-03-22'),  
    (17, 'Luke','Skywalker',Null,'2019-11-11'),  
    (18, 'Han','Solo',Null,'2012-02-03'),  
    (19, 'Kylo','Ren',Null,'2020-06-14'),  
    (20, 'Galen','Erso',Null,'2020-06-14');  

CREATE TABLE address   
(  
    PersonID integer,  
    address1 varchar(50), 
    address2 varchar(50),  
    city varchar(50),  
    state varchar(50),  
    zip int  
);  

INSERT INTO address (PersonID,address1, address2, city, state,zip)  
VALUES  
    (01, '1211 Sudan St' ,Null, 'Mobile','Al',36609),  
    (02, '4800 Barkshire Dr' ,Null, 'Pace','FL',32571),  
    (03, '12 Nutmeg Ct' ,Null,'Culver City','CA',90211),  
    (04, '2142 Elmwood Pl' ,Null,'Johnson City','TN',37112),  
    (05, '777 Heavenly Ln' ,'Box 13','Pike City', 'MN', 50877);  

CREATE TABLE contact  
( 
    id int,  
    cellphone varchar(150),   
    homephone varchar(150),  
    email varchar(150)  
);  

INSERT INTO contact(Id, cellphone, homephone, email)  
VALUES  
    (01, 5121325343, 5125234234,'apalmer@yachtmail.com' ),  
    (02, 5129739834, 5129847873,'sshepard@yorkdevtraining.com' ),  
    (03, 6453898502, 6459872345,' jsward2007@yahoo.com' ),  
    (04, 8763238756, 8763736548,' alsmith999@gmail.com' ),  
    (05, 8880345966, 8888567987,'james.betternot@hotmail.com' ),  
    (06, 3322827765, 3328760098,'ralph.white264@aol.com');
```

My query:

```
SELECT  
    employee.Firstname, employee.LastName, employee.age,  
    address.city, address.state 
FROM  
    employee  
INNER JOIN  
    address ON employee.PersonID = address.PersonID;
```

Comment: Sounds like a typically debugging scenario. Just go back and double-check that all tables exist and have been created correctly. It's part of the learning curve to power through these kinds of issues unfortunately.

Comment: PostgreSQL is a case-sensitive. Your field name is a `FirstName` not a `Firstname`